# Send logs using TLS over TCP to remote syslog server

Tags: winsock, syslog, winsock2, rsyslog

I am a newbie to the implementation of TLS over TCP.
I am using winsock to send TCP packets to remote syslog server just like the example given here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-client-code

Now I want to use TLS over TCP. I have configured rsyslog on my centOs machine(syslog server) according to these steps: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/secure-remote-logging-rsyslog-tls-certificate/
But above link states info about sending logs from one syslog server to another syslog server. I need to send logs from my application [cpp socket programming] to remote syslog server.

Can someone please help me, how should I achieve this? Do I need to store any certificate where my application is running or how should I make TLS over TCP from my application to remote syslog server.

Comment: This is a bit too broad to answer as asked.  You need to narrow the focus of your questioning. What exactly are you having trouble with in regard to using TLS over TCP? Have you tried anything yet? WinSock has no concept of TLS, so you will have to use a 3rd party library like OpenSSL, or you can use Microsoft's SChannel API. Neither of which is very trivial to use, as TLS itself is not trivial.

Comment: I have tried executed sending msgs from one syslog server to other: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/secure-remote-logging-rsyslog-tls-certificate/ . But in my case I need to send logs from cpp application to syslog server. In above link, the client which is sending msgs includes can.pem in it's rsyslog.conf file with other changes. I am not getting how should I implement handling of CA.pem in cpp application. Do I need to use external library like chilkat or openssl and their apis will handle all these things?